# Low CPU usage. How to increase it? Should I?

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm running a programme, and below are some graphics from the resources monitor from windows 8, while running my programme in version 9 of mathematica. Sorry for the foreign writings in the pics, but my windows is in Portuguese.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is why the low CPU usage by mathematica? Is there a way to change that limit, and should I change it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many kernels are your licensed for?  Is your code explicitly requesting parallel sub-kernels?  Im not massively familiar with the Linux task manager program but it looks to me as if your 32% CPU usage is coming from just 1 or 2 of the cores running at full capacity.  Try explicity starting some parallel kernels.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72259/131. You could supply more info on your system and the actual code you use, but the explanation is probably the same.

Comment: This [mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38979](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38979/threads-vs-cores-how-many-kernels-need-to-launch-in-parallel-mathematica?rq=1) is worth reviewing too.  Also see Evaluation -> Parallel Kernel configuration and Parallel Kernel status