# How many kernels to set based on CPU?

Tags: parallelization, kernel

[image]

Looks like 4 kernels are enough?

My CPU is i7 4790K as given [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz).

Does it also depend on the tasks and the codes?

My understanding is that regardless what the benchmark says, I could always use 8 kernels as my CPU can run 8 on cores? Most of the time, I would write my normal code and then execute them in batch using `Parallelize`.

I did find an old post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38979/threads-vs-cores-how-many-kernels-need-to-launch-in-parallel-mathematica), but as said, it is an old post. I wonder what's the general guidance in V10.1.0?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the task. The result given by *Mathematica*Mark is not generalizable to other contexts. And this is still assuming perfect parallelization... the `Parallel\`` package has a significant overhead associated with it as well. So I would suggest finding the optimum number by experiment in a case-by-case fashion. 8 would be the sensible maximum, of course.